# Animating routes in angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to animate route transitions in angular 4, the animation works when the page first loads, and on page refreshes, so I know the animation works, however not when I switch routes. what am I missing?

here is the code...

// component metadata

```
animations: [fadeInAnimation]
```

// tempalte

```
<div class="route-container" [@fadeInAnimation]>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

// styles

```
.route-container {
  position:relative;
}
.route-container>* {
  display:block;
}
```

// animation

```
trigger('fadeInAnimation', [

    // route 'enter' transition
    transition(':enter', [

        // css styles at start of transition
        style({ opacity: 0 }),

        // animation and styles at end of transition
        animate('6s cubic-bezier(.35,0,.25,1)', style({ opacity: 1 }))
    ]),
]);
```

Comment: You'll need to set up the trigger for each route. Right now it's only set for when 'router-outlet' appears, which is typically only once (when the app loads).

Comment: oh, that makes sense, where do I add the trigger for routed components, just the metadata? I know it's basic, but routed animations always trip me up.

Comment: I meant transition for each route, not trigger. The transition's first parameter will be `transition('route1 => route2', ....` and you'll need to `query(':enter',...` and `query(':leave', ...` for the different routes. I can add a more detailed answer below if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make sure routing animation proc on each route you will need to define transitions between each route. The following is an example that I use to create a drawer effect when transitioning between my 'home' route and my 'acct' route:

```
import { trigger, animate, style, group, query, transition } from '@angular/animations';

export const baseAnimation =
    trigger('baseAnimation', [
      transition('acct => home', [
        query(':enter, :leave', style({ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0 })),
        query(':leave', style({ height: '*'})),
        query('.acct', [
            animate('300ms',
            style({ height: 0 }))
        ])
      ]),
      transition('home => acct', [
        query(':enter, :leave',
          style({ position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, right: 0 })),
        query(':enter .acct', [
          style({ height: 0 }),
          animate('300ms', style({ height: '*' }))
        ])
      ])
    ])
```

Note that `.acct` refers to a class label for the account page route, and may not be necessary for your application (or may need to be changed accordingly). In this manner you can animate sub-elements of each route on route changes.

I use a function in my **app.component.html** to process route animations:

```
<div [@baseAnimation]="prepareRouteTransition(outlet)">
  <router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</div>
</div>
```

And the **app.component.ts** should load the animations and declare animations for the route:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { baseAnimation } from './anim/base.animation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  animations: [ baseAnimation ]
})

export class AppComponent {

  constructor() { }

  prepareRouteTransition(outlet) {
    const animation = outlet.activatedRouteData['animation'] || {};
    return animation['value'] || null;
  }
}
```

Comment: do I have to make any changes in the components themselves?  'home' or 'acct' in this case, do I have to pass in a query in the attribute? [@baseAnimation]=

Comment: You do not, unless you're animating by class. In the above case I wrap my entire component loaded from the 'acct' sub routes in a `<div class="acct">`  when I want them animated. If I don't want them animated I simply leave out that class and they load standard. I'll update my answer with my app.component.html as well.

Comment: @MelPacheco Updated answer