# Angular 5 How to start animation in a component (Ionic 3)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I'm using Angular 5 with Ionic 3. 
I'm trying to use Angular animations on my project. 
My current project has a main html page and an angular component nested inside.

The problem is.. I don't know how to trigger animation on component from a main page's button. 
My main page's button needs to trigger angular animation on texts of component which is rendered by using angular selector.

So here's my main html file.

```
<component1></component1>

<button (click)="startAnimations()">Trigger animation!</button>
```

and my main typescript file:

```
export class AppComponent {
  clickInfo = 'default';
  startAnimations() {
    this.clickInfo = 'clicked';
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.clickInfo = 'default';
    }, 10000);
  }
}
```

and here's my component html file which has contents that need to be animated. 
This div need to be animated by button click from main html:

```
<div [@clickedState]="clickInfo"></div>
```

and here's my animation ts which is properly imported to main typescript file.

```
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';


export const clickedStateTrigger = trigger('clickedState', [
    state('default', style({
      backgroundColor: 'orange',
      width: '100px',
      height: '100px',
      margin: '20px',

    })),
    state('clicked', style({
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      width: '300px',
      height: '500px',
      margin: '20px',

    })),

    transition('default => clicked', animate('200ms 500ms ease-in')),
    transition('clicked => default', animate(300))
  ])
```

Any idea? or github example of something similar? 
My current project will not trigger animation in component.. I guess it's mainly because component can't be accessed by main page's click function.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `@Input()`.

add to `component1`:

```
<component1 [clickInfo]="clickInfo"></component1>

<button (click)="startAnimations()">Trigger animation!</button>
```

add to your **component1.ts** file:

```
@Input('clickInfo') clickInfo: string;
```

Learn more about component interaction: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Learn how to use a general router outlet with animations:
[Animating routes in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45639268/animating-routes-in-angular-4/45643710#45643710)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try this shortly! really appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I solved the problem by not using animation as module. I directly inserted animation as animtion: [ ] in my component ts file and now it's working! thanks a lot!